# upgrade to dev version of scikit-learn on Anaconda?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, upgrade, anaconda

I'm using python through Anaconda, and would like to use a new feature (http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) in scikit-learn that's currently only available in the development version 0.18.dev0.

However, doing the classical `conda update` doesn't seem to work, as conda doesn't list any dev packages. What would be the simplest way to install a development version into my Anaconda? (For what it's worth, I'm using 64-bit windows 7.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can only use `conda` to install a package if someone has built and made available binaries for the package. Some packages publish nightly builds that would allow this, but scikit-learn is not one of them.

To install the bleeding-edge version in one command, you could use pip; e.g.:

```
$ conda install pip
$ pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

but keep in mind that this requires compiling all the C extensions within the library, and so it will fail if your system is not set up for that.

Comment: Thank you! My system is most likely not set up for that, so could you tell me how to find what is necessary for me to install?

Comment: There is some info here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#advanced-installation Just a warning: in general building compiled packages on Windows is a real PITA; it's why most people who use and develop this kind of code avoid that platform.

Comment: @user1111929, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge

You need C++ compiler, 
    Python,
    NumPy,
    SciPy.

Comment: Hmm... I have Microsoft's C++ compiler, but I get the error "AttributeError: MSVCCompiler instance has no attribute 'compiler_cxx'". Googling this didn't give me any steps towards a solution. Any idea what I should do with this?

Comment: @user1111929 I don't use Windows, but you could install https://www.cygwin.com/. It basically installs all Linux tools including compilers and so on, on top of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I had scikit-learn 0.17 which did not have MLPClassifier. I just did a conda update like below:

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

conda takes care of updating all dependent packages and after the update it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should build your own scikit-learn package on Anaconda. I did it in about 10 mins ([repo](https://github.com/jrkerns/machinelearning))([package](https://anaconda.org/jrkerns/scikit-learn/files)). The conda [tutorial](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs2.html) on how to build packages was helpful. There are probably more ways than one to do this, but I just downloaded the scikit-learn github repo, dropped it into a new repo, added a directory that housed my conda recipe, and then built the package from the recipe which [pointed to the source code](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#source-from-a-local-path) I just downloaded.

Comment: can you give more detailed instructions?