# Scikit dev branch and anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda

I want to install and use the neural network library of sklearn. I follow the instructions -> [upgrade to dev version of scikit-learn on Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568244/upgrade-to-dev-version-of-scikit-learn-on-anaconda). This installs the package in the folder /Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages and I indeed see the file scikit_learn-0.18.dev0-py2.7.egg-info and folder scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.7.egg-info/ in the above directory. But I get import error. What am I doing wrong? Any hints?

I checked that PYTHONPATH had the above directory in its path and also sys.path listed the directory as well. I also tried python -m pip install with same results.

I am on mac.

Comment: have you done `pip uninstall scikit-learn` before your dev branch install? Can you share the error message?

Comment: Thanks! I did a pip uninstall and a reinstall and now I get this error: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/uname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/arrayfuncs.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/uname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/arrayfuncs.so

Comment: Reason: image not found

Comment: what is the output of `mdfind -name libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib`?

Comment: /Users/uname/anaconda/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib

Comment: This worked for me: for lib in ~/anaconda/lib/*; do sudo ln -s $lib /usr/local/lib/$(basename $lib); done