# How to install scikit 0.19 dev version in anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am trying to install scikit 0.19 version with pip install. I am getting error message as

```
 File "C:\Users\Anitha Naveen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 58, in __init__
        dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Users\Anitha Naveen\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 157, in __init__
        self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
      File "C:\Users\Anitha Naveen\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 86, in get_msvcr
        raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
    ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
    [0x7FF91BFB1500] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
    [0x7FF91BFCD5E0] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
    [0x7FF91EDBF580] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
    [0x7FF91EDDA820] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
    [0x7FF91FA79E70] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scikit-learn
Command ""C:\Users\Anitha Naveen\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ANITHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-fiszbqmt\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ANITHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-f52l6cig-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANITHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fiszbqmt\scikit-learn\
```

Comment: Most of the questions are "very urgent", it doesn't mean you have to specify it to people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrade to dev version of scikit-learn on Anaconda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568244/upgrade-to-dev-version-of-scikit-learn-on-anaconda)

Comment: I tried the solutions of the above mentioned question. I am getting error in "cygwincompiler.py" . The error is  " valueError : unknown MS compiler version 1900".

Answer (score 0):

please try the official [instruction on installation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) of sklearn , if anything wrong happens again, please specify which version of your python and anaconda!